# Ошибка при установки библиотеки imgui - Python

Tags: python, windows, pip, library

Хотел установить библиотеку **`imgui`** (*PyImGui*, `pip install imgui`), но появляется ошибка.

Пишу команду

```
pip install imgui[full]
```

через какое-то время появляется следующая ошибка:

> Collecting cocos2d
> Using cached cocos2d-0.6.9.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> [7 lines of output]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 2, in 
> File "", line 34, in 
> File "C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-92o83qbv\cocos2d_5c5d947fd299447f9d4e34f4fba12730\setup.py", line 38, in 
> f = open('README.rst','rU')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU'
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
> ╰─> See above for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

что делать?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе версии питона и ОС. А не пробовали с гитхаба ставить? Видимо, на винде при установке через `pip` какие-то проблемы. В Google Colab нормально ставится.

Comment: Попытаться использовать предыдущую версию проблемного пакета

Comment: Попробуйте установить для конкретных задач, например `pip install imgui[pygame]`